# How to match text width to image without specifying exact widths?

Tags: html, css, image, width

I have this HTML:

```html
<article>
  <img src="image.jpg">
  <p> Text </p>
</article>
```

The text is placed underneath the image. Now I want the text to be the same width as the image, but I do not want to specify an exact width since the images are of different widths (so are the articles).

How can I make the text width correspond to the image width ie. making it break at the right time without specifying an exact width?

Comment: How is the size of the article determined? Do you specify the width or is it based off of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a CSS only solution. This might not work in all browsers yet, but certainly seems to work in the major ones.

```
article {
  width: -moz-min-content;  /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-min-content;   /* Webkit */    
  width: min-content;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U2Vxr/

And a full article on the matter: http://demosthenes.info/blog/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-MinContent

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked perfectly and I would rather use a css solution.

Answer (score 2):

You would need javascript to do this if the images aren't a set width.

Personally, I would do something like the following.

**HTML**

```
 <article>
 <img src="image.jpg" class="image" />
     <p> Text </p>
 </article>
```

**JS** -- jquery

```
$("article").each(function(i, obj) {
    var imgWitdh = $(obj).find(".image").width();
    $(obj).find("p").width(imgWidth);
});
```