# CSS: make text break at image width

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal scrolling image gallery, using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@oberon-amsterdam/horizontal).

I have images of the same height and variable width next to each other and for some of them I want to add text below. I don't want the text to become wider than the image. What's the best way to do that? The images should remain the same height each, all text would be added below.

I've simplified things a bit for this question and prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6qk48mc/1/) where I try to employ the first solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770439/how-to-match-text-width-to-image-without-specifying-exact-widths).  Doesn't work though.

**EDIT: I now realise I had a bracket in the wrong place in my jsfiddle, now it works:**

```
.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
 }  

  .card {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: -moz-min-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
    width: -webkit-min-content; /* Firefox/Gecko */    
    width: min-content;
}
```

I had:

```
    .scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
    
      .card {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: -moz-min-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
        width: -webkit-min-content; /* Firefox/Gecko */    
        width: min-content;
    }
}
```

Some copy/paste mistake I guess.

If the window is wide enough to create a gap between the pictures the text will get wider than the images.

Comment: Code that is included in external links only is discouraged. You can add the code from your fiddle into the question as a snippet which means it is available and can be run from directly in the question. It also lets users copy the snippet code into their answer with a click, makingit easier for us to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  }

  .card, .item {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
      background: lightgreen;
  width: -moz-min-content;  /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-min-content;   /* Firefox/Gecko */    
  width: min-content;
  }
```